# Time complexity of two algorithms running together?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Imagine T<sub>1</sub>(n) and T<sub>2</sub>(n) are running times of P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub> programs, and

T<sub>1</sub>(n) ∈ O(f(n))

T<sub>2</sub>(n) ∈ O(g(n))

What is the amount of T<sub>1</sub>(n)+T<sub>2</sub>(n), when P<sub>1</sub> is running along side P<sub>2</sub>?

The Answer is `O(max{f(n), g(n)})` but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we think about Big-O notation, we generally think about what the algorithm does as the size of the input `n` gets really big. A lot of times, we can fall back on some sort of intuition with math. Consider two functions, one that is `O(n^2)` and one that is `O(n)`. As `n` gets really large, both algorithms increases without bound. The difference is, the `O(n^2)` algorithm grows much, MUCH faster than `O(n)`. So much, in fact, that if you combine the algorithms into something that would be `O(n^2+n)`, the factor of `n` by itself is so small that it can be ignored, and the algorithm is still in the class `O(n^2)`.

That's why when you add together two algorithms, the combined running time is in `O(max{f(n), g(n)})`. There's always one that 'dominates' the runtime, making the affect of the other negligible.

Answer (score 1):

> The Answer is O(max{f(n), g(n)})

This is only correct if the programms run independently of each other. Anyhow, let's assume, this is the case.

In order to answer the *why*, we need to take a closer look at what the *BIG-O-notation* represents. Contrary to the way you stated it, it **does not represent time** but an **upperbound on the complexity**.

So while running both programms might take more time, the upperbound on the complexity won't increase.

Lets considder an example: P_1 calculates the the product of all pairs of n numbers in a vector, it is implemented using nested loops, and therefore has a complexity of `O(n*n)`. P_2 just prints the numbers in a single loop and therefore has a complexity of `O(n)`.

Now if we run both programms at the same time, the nested loops of P_1 are the most *'complex'* part, leaving the combination with a complexity of `O(n*n)`